# DataGridViewの編集中にマウスホイールを動かすと落ちる

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Visual Studio Professional 2015
Version 14.0.25123.00 Update 2
Microsoft .NET Framework Version 4.7.02046
C#

返信ありがとうございます。
シンプルな状態でエラーが再現したので投稿を編集しました。

拡張コントロール使用したらエラーが出ると書いていましたが、
拡張コントロールなしでエラーが発生することを確認しました。

発生状況・エラー内容
・`DataGridView`を設置する
・`DataGridView`の`CellValidating`の中で`DataGridView`の`EndEdit`メソッドを呼んでいる(1)
・`BindingSource`を設置する
・`DataSet`を作成する
・`DataSet`に項目が`「項目１」`のみの`DataTable`を作成する
・`BindingSource`の`DataSource`は作成した`DataSet`(2)
・`DataGridView`の`DataSource`は作成した`BindingSource`(3)
・`Form`起動時に`30`行のデータを表示する(4)
・1つのセルを選択し、値を削除した直後にマウスホイールを動かす
⇒エラー

```
型 'System.InvalidCastException' のハンドルされていない例外が System.Windows.Forms.dll で発生しました
追加情報:型 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxCell' のオブジェクトを型 'System.Windows.Forms.IDataGridViewEditingCell' にキャストできません。
```

ソース

(2)
this.bindingSource1.DataSource = this.dataSet11;

(3)
this.dataGridView1.DataMember = "DataTable1";
this.dataGridView1.DataSource = this.bindingSource1;

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // (4)
    for(var i=0; i<30; i++)
    {
        var dr = dataSet11.DataTable1.NewDataTable1Row();
        dr.項目１ = string.Format("{0}", i);
        dataSet11.DataTable1.AddDataTable1Row(dr);
    }
}

private void dataGridView1_CellValidating(object sender, DataGridViewCellValidatingEventArgs e)
{
    // (1)
    (sender as DataGridView).EndEdit();
}
```

マウスホイール時の処理中にエラーの原因があるのだろうと思い
以下のような対応をすると、エラーが出なくなりました。
が、原因を知った上で正しい対応をしたいです。
以上、よろしくお願いします

☆☆☆　エラーが出ない方法　☆☆☆

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    // MouseWheelイベント処理を作成する
    this.dataGridView1.MouseWheel += dataGridView1_MouseWheel;
}
// マウスホイールイベント
private void dataGridView1_MouseWheel(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    dataGridView1.CommitEdit(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Commit);
}
```

---

補足。色々していて、同じキャストエラーが出たソース

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    // MouseWheelイベント処理を作成する
    this.dataGridView1.MouseWheel += dataGridView1_MouseWheel;
}
// マウスホイールイベント
private void dataGridView1_MouseWheel(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    dataGridView1.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex = 3; // ここでエラーが出る
}
```

Comment: `CellTemplate`も変更しているようですし、普通に考えると質問で触れられていない「`DataGridViewTextBoxColumn`の拡張コントロール」の実装が悪いのだと思いますが。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

スタックトレースを確認すると[`DataGridView.OnMouseWheel`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/DataGridViewMethods.cs,ac6ff698b29aacb2)→[`DataGridView.CommitEdit`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/DataGridViewMethods.cs,317b04b624d9433e)→[`DataGridView.CommitEdit`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/DataGridViewMethods.cs,0b88877261864f06)で`InvalidCastException`が発生していますね。同メソッドにはいくつかキャストがありますので、いずれかの箇所で前提条件を満たしていないのだと思います。

原因はともかく、対策としては`DataGridView`の派生クラスで`OnMouseWheel`をオーバーライドすればよいと思います。

```
protected override void OnMouseWheel(MouseEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        base.OnMouseWheel(e);
    }
    catch
    {
    }
}
```